# Drupal - Use a CCK Date Field as RSS Date

Tags: drupal, rss

I'm trying to use a CCK Date field I created as the date for an RSS feed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Views RSS module](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss) lets you do that.